# csv.reader prints ['var'] instead of var

Tags: python, python-itertools

When I read a csv and sub the row value into a string variable is prints '['var']' but I need just var.

```
from itertools import islice
import csv


with open("test12.csv") as tl:
    for row in islice(csv.reader(tl), 0, None):
        rowlink = f"https://www.footballdb{row}/roster"
        print(rowlink)
```

this code prints

```
https://www.footballdb['test1']/roster
https://www.footballdb['test2']/roster
[Finished in 0.047s]
```

I need to remove the square brackets and quotations

thank you in advance

Comment: Add the expected output

Comment: try `rowlink = f"https://www.footballdb{row[2:-2]}/roster"`

Comment: What does `test12.csv` actually look like? And why are you using `islice`?

Comment: `csv.reader` always returns a list; you are printing that list rather than the first element of the list. `Use `row[0]` instead.

Comment: If you are thinking in terms of "remove the square brackets and quotations" then you *do not properly understand what is going on*. It's not a chunk of text that has square brackets and quotations in it; it's a *list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your csv file looks something like

```
test1
test2
```

And you're expecting a plain list like `['test1', 'test2']`.

The problem is that csv.reader should be returning a nested list, so it's more like `[['test1'], ['test2']]`.

You should be able to get the desired output as a string rather than a list, which you are currently printing, by selecting the first item in the list as follows:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv


with open("test12.csv") as tl:
    for row in islice(csv.reader(tl), 0, None):
        rowlink = f"https://www.footballdb{row[0]}/roster"
        print(rowlink)
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterator always yields a *list* of values for each row, even if the row has only one column. You are printing the entire list (whose string representation includes the brackets0, rather than just the first element of that list.

```
with open("test12.csv") as tl:
    for row in csv.reader(tl):
        rowlink = f"https://www.footballdb{row[0]}/roster"
        print(rowlink)
```